# Rmd to create html files that render mathjax/latex offline and after emailing

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, mathjax

I would like to create html output from my *.Rmd files that can be emailed to other people, and yet still render the latex/mathjax equations.

The reproducible example document below works perfectly for me--but as soon as I email it to myself, the equations are no longer rendered (image below, after the html has been emailed)--presumably because mathjax is no longer rendering it, and treating it as offline.

I've already tried `self_contained: yes` in the YAML header.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve installing a local copy of Mathjax, as the people I'm emailing won't have a local copy of Mathjax.

[image]

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "me"
date: "20/07/2019"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Equations

$$ y_i = mx_i + c$$
````

Comment: As far as I know, mathjax is not compatible with self_contained, see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#mathjax-equations. PDF may be a better option of "self_contained"  in your case.

Comment: Pandoc has other methods of rendering math. MathJax is unlikely to work offline. Try an image-based rendering method. I haven't tried by myself and don't have the time to help further. See if you can figure it out from the Pandoc manual: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html In R Markdown, use `mathjax: null` under `html_document` to disable MathJax, and `pandoc_args` to pass more Pandoc arguments (to enable a math rendering method).